# import javascript parts in main js file

Tags: javascript, webpack

Good day, I have a webpack assembly. There are also two script files, one of them is the main one, it is also connected to the page, and the second is for some settings. So I registered the settings I needed in this file and I want to import it into the main file, but I can’t do it. Tell me how to implement such an import

My settings js file

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
const menuIsActive = false

function menuOpen() {
  burger.classList.toggle('burger--active')
}

burger.addEventListener('click', menuOpen)
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with"I can't do it" (what trouble you're running into)? 
Doesn't something like `import './settings';` or `require('./settings.js')` work in your case?

Comment: oh sorry,  wrote the import like this import "nav.js" instead of this import "./nav.js"

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the import like this import "nav.js" instead of this import "./nav.js"